# How to change CMMI font to Palatino font in Equations

Tags: math-mode, fonts

How to change CMMI font to Palatino font in Equations

#### Source Code

```
\documentclass{book}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ppl}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}

Text font 

$$A + B = \frac{1}{2} \alpha $$

\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Add `\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}` or `\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}` to the preamble and remove the `\renewcommand` lines.

Comment: Note also that it's recommended to *not* use `$$ .. $$` for display math in LaTeX. Use  `\begin{equation*} .. \end{equation*}` (requires `\usepackage{amsmath}`) or `\[ .. \]` instead. See [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Comment: Please confirm that you want to change both the text font *and* the math font to Palatino. (The title of your query is a bit confusing, as it seems to suggest that you want Palatino only for math material but not for text material.)